# No such file or directory : 'Temp\\_MEI79882\\currency_converter\\eurofxref-hist.zip' error after compiling file from .py to .exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, currency, converters, file-not-found

I made prog that uses CurrencyConverter 0.14.2 module. It installs with 'pip install CurrencyConverter' command. When I compile that .py file to .exe file I'm getting this error:

```
File "currency_converter\currency_converter.py", line 154, in __init__
File "currency_converter\currency_converter.py", line 162, in load_file
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI79882\\currency_converter\\eurofxref-hist.zip'
[2652] Failed to execute script convert currency
```

Also I am convering dollars to euros
Code:

```
from currency_converter import CurrencyConverter
c = CurrencyConverter()
usd_to_euro = input("How many dollars? \n")
converted = c.convert(usd_to_euro, 'USD', 'EUR')
print(converted)
```

Maybe somebody knows why this error occurs and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue. I found that if you initialize the converter with a link to the zip file of rates it fixes the error.

```
c = CurrencyConverter('http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.zip')
```